# repeated measures ANOVA - non-experimental data

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, stata

For every year, for eight years, I have a set of projects (n=332). The number of projects that exist in each year varies (for example, some years there are 10 projects others there are 60).   In each year, projects are either approved or not approved based on a score.  I want to compare the means for approved and not approved projects for each year as well as compare the scores for approved and not approved projects over time.  A repeated measures ANOVA with contrasts lets me do this but because the projects are not the same every year I believe this is not the right test.  Thoughts?

Also, the scores used to approve or not approve a project is a sum of several sub-scores.  I want to compare the standard deviations about the project score for both approved and not approved project and over time.

PS a mixed model, projects within years in STATA won't converge

Comment: When Stata fails to converge, does it tell you anything about what went wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a repeated measures approach?

Comment: I am using repeated measures b/c the post hoc contrasts lets me easily compare the means for the two groups approved and not approved and the means in each year.  Which seem to me better than doing t-tests for each year.